# Could not open source file in embedded workbench (Fatal Error[Pe005]) in IAR Embedded workbench 4.0

Tags: iar

I am trying to include some header files (example: #include  "dir2/dir3/ecc.h") in a C file (flash.c). Compiler gives an error that it cannot open the source file and I am not able to figure out where the problem is.

Under project -> options -> c/C++ Compiler -> Preprocessor -> additional include directories, I have added path to the folder that contains this header file i.e., $PROJ_DIR$\dir1\

So the folder structure is:

```
-dir1

   -dir2

      -dir3

         -ecc.h
```

The problem goes away if I use relative path like #include  "../dir2/dir3/ecc.h". Also, this problem is only with one build configuration and other configurations compile with no errors.

I am not sure what else to try. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"Also, this problem is only with one build configuration and other configurations compile with no errors."* Maybe you forgot to add additional include directory to one configuration that fails?

Comment: @user694733 It was missing when I initially started working on this configuration but even after adding it, compiler is not able to find files.